# SVG in viewBox, CSS in the "box-sizing: border-box;" When used in combination, position becomes point

Tags: svg

**Why, "box-sizing: border-box;" only when it is used, and become a point?**

Please tell me whether guided by what formula?

---

**Chrome Version**

44.0.2403.157 m

---

**Do not use box-sizing**

```
<style>
svg {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg preserveAspectRatio="none" viewBox="0 0 2000 400" width="500" height="400">
  <rect id="hoge" x="50" y="50" width="50" height="50"/>
</svg>
<script>
  console.log($("#hoge").offset()); //Object {top: 59, left: 21.5}
</script>
```

---

**use box-sizing**

```
<style>
svg {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
* {
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
}
</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg preserveAspectRatio="none" viewBox="0 0 2000 400" width="500" height="400">
  <rect id="hoge" x="50" y="50" width="50" height="50"/>
</svg>
<script>
  console.log($("#hoge").offset()); //Object {top: 58.75, left: 21.450000762939453}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use border-box the width of content is changed, instead of using 400px in height it can now only use (400px - 2px) 398px. Because of that the svg itself has to displayed smaller.

The underlaying calculations for your example looks as follows:
`offset.top = margin of body + border + (svg content height / viewBox height * rect y)`

In your first example this means
:`8px (default value) + 1px + (400px / 2000 * 50) = 59`

Your second example:
`8px (default value) + 1px + (398px / 400 * 50) = 58.75`

Read [this css-tricks article](https://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/) for further explanation of the box model.

Comment: It was exactly what I wanted to know answers.Thank you for a detailed description!